# Which pam module is used for gnome admin password requests?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, pam, yubikey

I have added the yubikey pam module to my sudo pam config, and I like the results—no one can get superuser access through sudo or su without a yubikey.

Setting aside the fact that this is possibly excessive security for a personal machine, I am trying to figure out how to require the yubikey for gnome admin upgrade password requests also, but I don't want to use it to log in/unlock the screen, just to gain admin access.

However, when I look at the pam modules, I see `gdm-password` and `login` (plus others of course), neither of which seems ideal for what I want to do.

Is it possible to do this? If so, which pam module would I need to alter?

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, gnome-shell 3.28.1, kernel version  4.15.0-23-generic

Comment: That is probably the GNOME polkit authentication agent, and the corresponding PAM stack would be polkit's (`/etc/pam.d/polkit-1`).

Comment: Correct! That worked. Would you mind re-writing as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most GUI prompts on a modern Ubuntu release are for authenticating to Polkit: the Software update/install prompts, changing settings in Disks or User Accounts, etc. Additionally, on the command line, using `systemctl` (and `systemctl`-based commands like `shutdown`, `reboot`, etc.) also authenticate via Polkit (if you don't use `sudo`). For all of these, the applicable PAM stack would be Polkit's: `/etc/pam.d/polkit-1`.

Comment: For anyone who wants to add offline yubikey 2FA for root access, you can follow the guide here: https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/Authentication_Using_Challenge-Response.html but instead of using the common-auth module, use the `polkit-1` module like muru says, as well as the `sudo` and `su` modules. Be aware you can permanently lock yourself out of your system if you aren't careful.